# Actualización de vista en tiempo real con AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de manejar la actualización `push` en AngularJS en la vista pero me ha quedado imposible. Sé lo siguiente:

- Tengo un arreglo, este arreglo se llama `marca1` y recibe todos los objetos que trae la petición `get` que realizo al servidor y se muestra en la vista con `ng-repeat`.
- Cuando envío la petición `post` para guardar un nuevo dato, ésta obtiene una respuesta del server que la guardo en un objeto llamado `pepa`.
- Utilizo la función `push` para que mi arreglo actualice la vista, pero eso no funciona.

¿Por qué puede estar fallando?¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi codigo:

```
miAppAngular.controller('marca',function($scope,$http,$location, $routeParams,configuracionGlobal){

  $scope.config = configuracionGlobal;
  $scope.marca1=[];

  $http.get( configuracionGlobal.api_url + "/marca/listaMarca.php")
    .then( function(respuesta){
    $scope.marca1=respuesta.data;
  });

  $scope.nuevaMarca = function ( ){  
    $scope.newMarca={
      'nombre':$scope.nombreMarca
    }

    $scope.pepa={};
    //     
    $http({
      url: configuracionGlobal.api_url + "/marca/nuevaMarca.php",  
      method: "POST",
      data: $scope.newMarca,   
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
      .then(
      function(respuesta){
        $scope.pepa= respuesta;
        $scope.marca1.push($scope.pepa);

        $('#modalMarca').modal('hide');
      }
    )         
  }
```

Comment: prueba con ` $scope.pepa= respuesta.data;` dentro del then de la llamada post

Comment: Hola si pongo $scope.pepa=respuesta.data y le digo que imprima en la consola la respuesta es 'OK' pero si lo dejo sin el .data la consola me arroja esto

Comment: Hola si pongo $scope.pepa=respuesta.data y le digo que imprima en la consola la respuesta es 'OK' pero si lo dejo sin el .data e imprimo marca1 con la funcion push como esta en la pregunta me envia esta repuesta Array[26]Object
25
:
Object
config
:
Object
data
:
Object
nombre
:
"p21"
__proto__
como si ya estuviera dentro del arreglo pero no lo muestra en la vista hasta que actualiza pagina o hasta que cambia la vista teniendo en cuenta que p21 seria el nuevo dato

Comment: podrías poner console.log(JSON.stingify($scope.pepa)) para que te muestre la información. tambien podrías indicar como muestras la informacion en la vista y como agregas los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Basado en el log que obtienes (Array[26]Object 25) quiere decir que "/marca/nuevaMarca.php" esta respondiendo con un arreglo por lo que al hacer push a ese arreglo terminas con algo como [{dato:1}, [{dato:2}]], esto puede ser por que nuevaMarcar desde tu API debería de contestar con algo como {dato:2} pero esta contestando con [{dato:2}].

Me parece que te podría servir agregar el

```
$scope.newMarca={
  'nombre':$scope.nombreMarca
}
```

a tu arreglo:

```
 $scope.marca1.push($scope.newMarca);
```